# How I can fix the next error in Visual Studio 2010 C#?

Tags: c#

I'm working in the project to the faculty, called loans project.

This is for SQL Server, `ConsultaClientes` is the stored procedure:

```
public static void OrdenarClienteSP(Cliente oCliente)
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ClasesBase.Properties.Settings.Default.conex);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "ConsultaClientes";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = cnn;

    // Parametros del comando
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ape", oCliente.Cli_Apellido);

    // Abrir la conexion
    cnn.Open();

    // Ejecuta la consulta (insert)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     // Here the error happens

    // Cierro la conexion
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Here is the view called `FrmGestionCliente`, in which you click with a radio button for the order that is in the data seen ascending from the last name

```
private void btnOrdenarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cliente oCliente = new Cliente();

    //oCliente.Cli_Apellido = (string)txtApellido.ToString();

    if (rbnApellido.Checked)
    {
        TrabajarCliente.OrdenarClienteSP(oCliente);
    }
}
```

Here is the stored procedure `ConsultaClientes`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ConsultaClientes
    /*
    (@parameter1 INT = 5,
     @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT)
    */
    (@ape VARCHAR(50))
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    SELECT * 
    FROM Cliente 
    ORDER BY CLI_Apellido DESC

    RETURN
```

Error:

> Procedure or function 'ConsultaClientes' expects parameter '@ape', which was not supplied

Comment: Hello and welcome! What is the code for `ConsultaClientes`?

Comment: Can `oCliente.Cli_Apellido` be `NULL` ? You might need to explicitly check for that, and if so, insert `DBNull.Value` for your parameter

Answer (score 2):

Can `oCliente.Cli_Apellido` be `NULL`?

You might need to explicitly check for that, and if so, insert DBNull.Value for your parameter - something like this:

```
// Parametros del comando
if (oCliente.Cli_Apellido == null)
{
    // if this value is NULL, use "DBNull.Value" for your parameter
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ape", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value =  DBNull.Value;
}
else
{ 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ape", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value =  oCliente.Cli_Apellido);
}
```

You might need to adapt the `SqlDbType.VarChar, 100` to whatever your parameter's type is - I'd **strongly** recommend always **explicitly** defining that type and using this syntax, instead of using the `.AddWithValue()` (where SQL Server must **guess** what type you might be meaning....)

For more information and background on why to **avoid** `.AddWithValue`, read this: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Nice answer. I admit that I didn't know that AddWithValue is evil

Comment: @BogdanDoicin: that's what SO is all about - you learn something new (almost) every day ! :)

Comment: To complete your answer: do you think that his stored procedure could have a bug, and not include the `@ape` parameter? This was my first thought when I read this Q

Comment: @BogdanDoicin: without seeing the procedure code, it's hard to tell - but the error message seems to indicate that there **is** a parameter - but no value is supplied to it.

Comment: Sorry here is the Store Procedure i will add it up:

Comment: @marc_s 
I do not get the error, but now when I click on the button it does not do anything, I do not get any error

Comment: @Cpp or maybe it does do something, but you don't get any notifications. What is it written in the database after the code in the answer is ran?